# rails 6 form input element change event handler in javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

This isn't working since upgrading to rails 6 with webpacker I don't know if my syntax is vanilla or jquery Can someone tell me please I think I need to add a jquery.min.js script tag to my html I'm not sure

```
    document.on("turbolinks:load", () => {

        $('#element_id').change(function(e) {
        // do something
        })

    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add jQuery with yarn first

```
$yarn add jquery
```

Then you need to configure your jQuery in config/webpack/environment.js

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery'
  })
)

module.exports = environment
```

Create your jQuery code and put the .js file inside app/javascript/packs and register/import your code in app/javascript/packs/application.js

```
import Rails from "@rails/ujs"
import Turbolinks from "turbolinks"
import * as ActiveStorage from "@rails/activestorage"
import "channels"
import "jquery"
import "packs/sample1" // this will be sample1.js file
import "packs/sample2"
import "packs/styles.scss"

Rails.start()
Turbolinks.start()
ActiveStorage.start()
```

That should work, good luck coding, enjoy Rails!

Answer (score 0):

Might be a small mistake. I think you have missed the parenthesis.

```
$(document).on("turbolinks:load", () => {

    $('#element_id').change(function(e) {
      // do something
    })

})
```